# Create an Association with Key->Value dependent on a previous Key->Value

Tags: associations

I am trying to find a way to create an association (preferably without iterating) with values dependent on other values in the association.

I know that this is incorrect, but an attempt that I've made is

```
assoc = <|"A" -> RandomInteger[{1, 10}], "B" -> 10 - assoc[["A"]]|>
```

So I just want A to be a RandomInteger between 1 and 10, and then B be the remainder up to 10.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this as

```
assoc = <|"A" -> #, "B" -> 10 - #|>& @ RandomInteger[{1, 10}]
(* <|"A" -> 9, "B" -> 1|> *)
```